# Monogame WP8 Ambiguous Reference

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

I am trying to create a Windows Phone 8 library that uses MonoGame. So I create a solution and then add a new WP8 library project. If I reference a MonoGame dll it causes ambiguous reference for types like Color or Vector2 since its conflicting with the Microsoft ones. [This blog](http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/monogame-using-libraries-with-windows-phone-projects/) suggests that I should instead just download the MonoGame NuGet package and it'll solve the issue, but it doesnt and the project still complains that it cant resolve symbols like 'Texture2D'. I also tried to insert the following text in my .csproj file manually since the NuGet package doesnt seem to be doing it itself, but nothing changed.

```
<Target Name="MonoGame_RemoveXnaAssemblies" AfterTargets="ImplicitlyExpandTargetFramework">
  <Message Text="MonoGame - Removing XNA Assembly references!" Importance="normal" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Remove="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(Filename)%(Extension)'=='Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll'" />
    <ReferencePath Remove="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(Filename)%(Extension)'=='Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices.dll'" />
    <ReferencePath Remove="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(Filename)%(Extension)'=='Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServicesExtensions.dll'" />
    <ReferencePath Remove="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(Filename)%(Extension)'=='Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.dll'" />
    <ReferencePath Remove="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(Filename)%(Extension)'=='Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibraryExtensions.dll'" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I cant figure out whats going wrong here. I tried all guides and methods but no results.

Answer (score 0):

if you have solution file of monogame for windows phone 8 then add that solution to your solution  of project and in references remove other references and add the monogame solution as a reference